# How to disable tslint for an unused import in Angular

Tags: typescript, tslint

I've a small project. I wanted to create a production built for the same. I used this command:

`ng build --prod`

But it was throwing some build errors. So I asked my tech lead and she told me add this import:

`import ResizeObserver from 'resize-observer-polyfill'`

The build was successful after this but now the files are not passing linting test. Since the import is not used anywhere else in this code. I'm getting this error:

> ERROR: C:/Users/320035648/Angular/pinc-insights-ui/src/app/app.module.ts:29:1 - All imports on this line are unused.
> Lint errors found in the listed files.

So I added this line before the import:

`/* tslint: disable: no-unused-variable */`

But still I'm getting same error. Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not using `ResizeObserver`, and so only using library import side-effects, why not simply importing the library this way:

```js
import 'resize-observer-polyfill'
```